# Hungerford's Abstract Algebra (An Introduction) 3rd ed. Section 4.4 example #4.

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is from Hungerford's Abstract Algebra (An Introduction) 3rd ed.  Section 4.4 example #4.

The example verbatim from book:
The polynomial $x^2+1 \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ has no roots in $\mathbb{R}$ because there are no real-number solutions of the equation $x^2+1=0$. However, if $x^2+1$ is considered as a polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[x]$, then it has $i$ and $-i$ as roots because these are the solutions in $\mathbb{C}$ of $x^2+1=0$.

So my understanding of a polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is that $x$ is an indeterminate (transcendental element) (as explained in the book on the same page) of the ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$.  So $x$ is not in
$\mathbb{R}$ but all the coefficients are in $\mathbb{R}$.  So since $x$ is not in $\mathbb{R}$, couldn't we have $i$ and $-i$ as solutions while still considering the polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$?  I would have thought we only need to consider consider the polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ if the coefficients were not real.

My second question -- when the text talks generally about $\mathbb{R}[x]$ and says $x$ is an indeterminate (transcendental element) of the ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$, why does $x$ have to come from outside $\mathbb{R}$?  That was not exactly clear to me.

Comment: There's a nice analogy between factoring objects in a ring in algebra and dissolving a substance into a solution in chemistry. It's not just about the object that you intend to decompose. It's also relevant how strong your solvent is! Hence, $x^2 + 1$ is irreducible in the ring of polynomials with real coefficients, even though $x^2 + 1 = (x - i)(x + i)$ with the stronger solvent (polynomials with complex coefficients).

Comment: The issue here is closure as you have to leave the ring the polynomials are defined over to find solutions. To arrive at the conclusion that $\pm i$ are solutions you have to know a priori that the reals are a subfield of the complex numbers. A better approach is to construct a larger field from the polynomial ring that has solutions. For example you can construct the complex number by considering real polynomials modulo $x^2+1$, which is where I assume the text is going with this.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to think about $x$ in this context is as a symbol that we can plug values that are chosen from $\mathbb R$ or outside of it. We searched far and wide for a real number whose square is $-1$ and failed to come up with something. That's what we mean when we say "The polynomial $x^2+1 \in \mathbb R[x]$ has no solutions **in** $\mathbb R$".

You point out that $i, -i \in \mathbb C$ are roots of $x^2+1 = 0$. This means we can say "The polynomial $x^2+1 \in \mathbb R[x]$ has $2$ solutions **in** $\mathbb C$". The "solutions in" part focuses on where we are picking values to plug into the polynomial expression $x^2+1$.